# How to find angle between forward of player and camera forward directions in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector

How to find angle between forward of player and camera forward directions in Unity?

I have 2 independent gameobjects on the scene such as player and camera. Camera folows player and can move arround him thanks to the cinema machine.

I has no idea how to valculate angle between player forward direction and camera forward direction except code below

```
 var projectedTransformForward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(_transform.forward, Vector3.up);
 var projectedCameraForward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(_cameraTreansform.forward, Vector3.up);
 var angle = Vector3.Angle(projectedCameraForward, projectedTransformForward);
```

Please, help or correct me:D)

[image]

Find angle between forward of player and camera forward directions

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Does the example code not return an angle? Is the angle not what you expected, if so, what did you expect? what did you get?

Comment: You could use Mathf.LerpAngle(angle1,angle2,0.5) to get the angle halfway between, or any other number between 0 and 1 to have it weighted.

Comment: Are you only interested in the size of the angle? Then what you have should do the trick ... if you also need the direction you would probably rather use `SignedAngle` .. currently you also map both on a the XZ plane .. if you need the absolute 3D angle well then skip that ;)

Comment: So where is the problem in this code?